# How to construct quotient sets (types?) in Martin-Löf type theory

Tags: logic, type-theory

I think there is no formation rule for quotient type. How to construct quotient set in Martin-Löf type theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional approach to quotients in type theory is to avoid them completely by using setoids instead. In this approach we equip a type $X$ with an equivalence relation $E$ to get a *setoid*, which is just the pair $(X, E)$. If $(X, E)$ and $(X', E')$ are setoids, we say an *operation* is a map $X \to Y$, and a *function* is an operation that also preserves the equivalence relations. If we want to quotient a setoid $(X, E)$ by an equivalence relation $F$, we don't touch $X$ at all, but we replace $E$ with the new (typically larger) equivalence relation $F$.

A more modern approach is to extend type theory but adding quotient types. This was done for extensional type theory in e.g. Maietti, *[Modular correspondence between dependent
type theories and categories including
pretopoi and topoi](http://www.math.unipd.it/~maietti/papers/tumscs.pdf)*. Quotient types are also included in homotopy type theory, as a kind of higher inductive type.